# Does Entity Framework work well for large db with 800+ tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have 869 tables in a database. Should I go with Entity Framework (version 4) or plain old ADO.NET?

I'm sitting on the fence as to which way to swing -- EF (version 4) or plain old ADO.NET, with a mild incline towards Entity Framework. I am only worried whether the Entity Framework model designer will freeze at such a large data model and if it will be a nightmare to maintain.

Have any of you tried using Entity Framework with such a large data set?

Answer (score 1):

The number of tables in the database doesn't really impact the choice of data access layer framework.

EF is good at what it does, and using EF would result in far less code than the equivalent in ADO.NET.

Therefore, I'd nearly always recommend EF over ADO.NET.

Comment: I agree with you about EF being nice. I've been using EF for 2+ years now. I have never used it with such large a database, though, so I am interested in finding out if anyone has.

Comment: Ok, that's good. What concerns do you have? I can understand if the relationships are difficult to model but you can have that problem with 20 tables, I wouldn't see that as a table-number issue.

Answer (score 1):

This based on experience. We are online betting company so our data transfer involves real time delivery. We did some benchmarks comparing the speed of query using EF and ADO.NET and we found out that ADO.NET is almost 4 times faster than EF. If your tables have one to many relationships or have complex relationships it would be heavier for your application to use EF. Why? Because if you are querying using EF it gets not only the data from main table but also getting records from child tables. Unless you are using "projection" from LINQ queries that somehow makes your object lighter.

In the end there is one thing that you should consider WHEN NOT to use EF.

*Don't use EF if your priority is delivering or inserting data as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

With that many tables for EF4 and EF5 you may need to use pre-generated views if you experience slow start. You probably want to take a look at [performance considerations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/05/ef5-performance-considerations.aspx) - these are EF5 specific but a lot of information still applies to EF4 or at least should give you a sense what areas you need to be careful about. 
If possible use .NET Framework 4.5 - there were [significant performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/14/sneak-preview-entity-framework-5-0-performance-improvements.aspx) improvements in this version.